# Running Linux and Windows (dual-boot and virtualize the same machines) and hibernate

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, virtualization, hibernate

Let's imagine the following scenario:

- You have Linux and Windows installed on the same computer in a way that you can boot and virtualize the same machines.
- You're currently running Ubuntu on the host.
- Win7 is running inside of a virtual machine on that host.
- Inside of that VM there are more than 20 applications running and you can't close them and shut down until you're finished with a project (unless you want to waste hours of time).
- Now you suddenly realize that it would be nice to have some more horse power especially GPU-wise and put the VM into hibernate so that you can boot it natively...

Would that even be possible?

I'm also wondering what would happen if the Win7 system was already running a couple of VMs. Running VMs inside of another VM, is that a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the following

> Now you suddenly realize that it would be nice to have some more horse power especially GPU-wise and put the VM into hibernate so that you can boot it natively...

In my understanding, there is nothing that prevents you from hibernating a Guest OS (Virtual Machine) and booting the Host OS. But, you want to boot into windows7 or linux after it? If Linux, no issue. If Win7, I do not see a way to "Natively" boot it from the virtual disk.

Comment: You should ask for more information in the form of a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I am talking about hibernating the Win7 machine while it's being virtualized and then shutting down the host and booting that Win7 natively which was virtualized before. I know that this is possible if you do a shut down instead of a hibernate.

Comment: So, If the Virtualised machine used Physical Drive, it can be "Technically" Resumed/booted into. But to the best of my knowledge, if the same partition is used to boot in the Physical as well as Virtual environments, Windows might come up with strange errors like incompatible drivers and occasionally licensing warnings.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_%28computing%29#Microsoft_Windows:

> On Windows computers, hibernation is available only if all hardware
>   and device drivers are ACPI and plug-and-play–compliant.

Although there's no citation for this sentence on the wiki page, but AFAIR this is true. And I don't remember any VM fulfils that criterion.

Comment: I have done this before, so it is possible. I guess you can simply virtualize ACPI.